# Fade in and out background image on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

In a slider with background image as image of the slide, i want to change the background image when the mouse is hover a button, with a transition effect, and return to first image when the mouse leave the button. The first image have a blur effect while the second haven't it. I know how to change the image, but can't find a solution to apply a transition effect

```
$('#open-wowstyle').hover({
    $('#img-wowstyle').css("background-image","image2.jpg");
});
$('#open-wowstyle').mouseleave({
    $('#img-wowstyle').css("background-image","image1.jpg");
});
```

Also, I don't know why but the event "mouseleave" won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Changing image by css url will not support css transition. You can place images in separate elements like DIV and position DIVs in exact same position using `position: absolute`. Now you can change the `opacity` of the DIVS on hover. The opacity property will support css transition.

Please check the below example. The ugly text is the image url from google. sorry for that.

```js
$('.click').hover(function(){
  $('.hover-bg-2').fadeOut(300);
});

$('.click').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.hover-bg-2').fadeIn(300);
});
```

```css
.me{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.hover-bg-1,
.hover-bg-2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.hover-bg-1{
  background: yellow url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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');
}
.hover-bg-2{
  background: red url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="me">
  Im the content here
  <div class="hover-bg-1"></div>
  <div class="hover-bg-2"></div>
</div>
<button class="click">clickme</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it look a good solution, i have to apply the transition code (css) in the .css() function?

Comment: Yes, you apply transition in css, Since :hover is supported by css itself, no need of jQuery here.

Comment: Sorry @gattass69. I misunderstood your requirement. It need jQuery. on button hover(), you may use fadeIn() and fadeout() to get transition. Another option is to toggle a class and use css opacity transition.

Comment: I can't change background image with fadeToggle effect, am i right?

Comment: I am preparing a working example. Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and check the working sample by hovering the button.

Comment: It should work, i know, but inside SlitSlider it won't work. Adding another div with the image cause the stop of the entire slider, so i'm looking for a solution to change only the image-background applied in the div..without creating any clone

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :hover with animate, purly done with js and css no jquery.

```css
#btn {
  /* background-color: red; */
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
       width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(http://th07.deviantart.net/fs70/150/i/2013/012/c/6/rock_01_png___by_alzstock-d5r84up.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#btn:hover {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: 0.3s;
   background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/gazelle2.cdn.yolocare.com/sites/370/2015/05/line-art-icons-150x150-activity.png);

}
```

```html
  <button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: but the background image is in another div, not in the button, can I apply your solution to my code maintaining background-image instead of making two different div?

Comment: @gattass69 there is one HTML elelement `  <button id="btn">Button</button>`  no two divs. Just apply the css I described on one element with the `:hover` directive and you will get the desired effect.

Comment: But i have a div with background image, and a button:hover->change image of div

Comment: Maybe for my english, hope someone can edit the question with a good english

Comment: @gattass69 can you reproduce the problem here: https://jsbin.com/ save it and share the url so I can work on your . issue.